# What is the difference between Frege's and Descartes' theory of ideas?

Tags: descartes, frege, idea

Frege discusses the ideas (Vorstellungen) in Logical Investigations part I: Thoughts. Descartes discusses the ideas (the imagination) in Meditation VI. We have to find a similarity and a difference between these two with quotes from the texts. I simply can't find a difference between  them.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the user!

Answer (score 1):

For Frege, [*thought* (Gedanke)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2251513) is objective while *idea* (Vorstellung) is mental.

The thought is the "conceptual content" expressed by a sentence.

Ideas live in the so-called second realm of mental facts, while thoughts live in the third realm of timelessly truth.

According to [Descartes’ Theory of Ideas](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes-ideas/), ideas are *modes* of the thinking substance, and thus they are in the mind.

Up to now, no differences. But the basic difference is that in Descartes' ontology there is no third world: concepts (and thoughts) are mental entities as well.

Compare with [Locke's theory of ideas](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/locke/#BookIII) (quite similar to Descartes on this point) :

> “words in their primary or immediate signification signify nothing but the ideas in the mind of him that uses them”.

This, in a nutshell, for Descartes *ideas* are the meaning of words/sentences, while for Frege they are not.